# I have a problem with the function Directory.delete?

Tags: c#

Take a look at my code:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Hackers.avi")))
                Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Hackers.avi"), true);
```

after runing the file is still exist on my desktop , why??

Comment: So, is "Hackers.avi" a file or a directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unlikely that `Hackers.avi` is a directory - `.avi` is normally used an extension for a video **file** (see [Audio Video Interleave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) on Wikipedia for more information).

Try using [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) instead of `Directory.Delete`:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
try
{
    string pathToFile = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Hackers.avi");
    File.Delete(pathToFile);
    // etc...
```

I also omitted the call to `File.Exists` because you don't have to check for a file's existence before deleting it. `File.Delete` does not throw if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete file, sou you must use 'File.Delete'